# One common registration form with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, forms

In our sales organization we have three different sales channels (three different web systems). One of the sales channels is built with MVC3 and the two others with Web Forms.

We are launching a new product which all of these sales channels will try to sell. We would be glad if we don’t have to build three different registration forms for this product (and also avoid this for new products in the future).

In other words we don’t want to repeat ourselves when writing code, but we want the “common” registration form to be nicely integrated with the existing sale systems.

How should we do this? 
(We have thought about IFrame or a new “common” registration form that is loaded, with query strings, from the other systems.)

**EDIT:**

Moved from my comment: *"I'm not so interested in the details (how to store data in the database and so on, I know how to do that). For this solution: I’m planning to build one form (as you also mentioned in the comment) in the main sales channel system. Use an IFrame (that point to the main form URL) in the other sales channel and fill the form with query string. Does this sound as a good overall architecture?"*

Comment: Do the three sales channels have different user data stores or is it just the UI that is copied?

Comment: I'm not 100% that I understood you. These are three different web projects but they all uses the same database (the same customer base).

Comment: The only true answer to this is 'It depends.'. Although reasonably worded your question fails to explain how the data is stored. SQL, XML, CSV and as the user above mentions is it in the same datastore across the 3 systems? Whatever the answer, it will likely be possible to write a single form that is hosted in one of the 3 environments and inserts data across all of them but the details of such a solution would require much more information in your post.

Comment: The same datastore across the 3 systems. The data is stored in a SQL database.

Comment: Well that would most likely significantly reduce the complexity of implementing the solution but again the details of such a solution are far beyond the scope of what we can provide you here BUT basically all you need to do is look at the schema of the table you would like to insert into, build a form around it and host it in one of your 3 environment however without concise details (Such as the approach you want to use in inserting data in the database, ADO, Webservices, MSMQ) on your part that's about all the answer you're likely to get.

Comment: I'm not so interested in the details (how to store data in the database and so on, I know how to do that). For this solution:  I’m planning to build one form (as you also mentioned in the comment) in the main sales channel system. Use an IFrame (that point to the main form URL) in the other sales channel and fill the form with query string. Does this sound as a good overall architecture?